# QueryOver using an ignored property

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

I have two entities:

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int ParentId 
    { 
        get
        {
            if (Parent != null)
                return Parent.Id;
            return -1;
        }

        set
        {
            if (Parent != null)
                Parent = new Parent();
            Parent.Id = value;
        } 
    }

    protected virtual Parent Parent
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

The `Parent` property is set up like this to simplify the API side, and I do not want to change it to expose this property publicly.  I have an override of the mappings for the `Child` class to accommodate this:

```
public class ChildMappingOverrides : IAutoMappingOverride<Child>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Child> mapping)
    {
        mapping.References<Parent>(Reveal.Member<Child>("Parent")).Column("Parent_id");
        mapping.IgnoreProperty(x => x.ParentId);
    }
}
```

Now, if I want to query all the `Child` objects for a given parent Id, I would perform this:

```
session.QueryOver<Child>().Where(c => c.ParentId == 1);
```

However, this throws a `QueryException`:

> could not resolve property: ParentId of: My.Namespace.Child

How can I retrieve the set of `Child` objects that have a particular `Parent` Id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but you could try this:

```
session.QueryOver<Child>()
    .Where(Restrictions.Eq(
        Projections.SqlProjection(
            "{alias}.Parent_id as ParentId",
            new[] { "ParentId" },
            new[] { NHibernateUtil.Int32 }), 1))
    .List<Child>();
```

You're not going to be able to query on unmapped associations in any NHibernate query, but this at least minimizes the loss of compile-time checking.

This is somewhat limited from what I can tell. `{alias}` will always be replaced by the alias of the *root* entity, meaning if you want to do this for a more complex query that doesn't start with `Child`, you might be out of luck.

Comment: I like that fractionally more :)  Thanks Andrew, it works with a small tweak that I made just to match the column name in my example.

Comment: @PatrickQuirk: No problem-- I wish there was a more solid way to do what you're after

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by using `CreateSQLQuery` instead of `QueryOver`:

```
session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT C.* FROM CHILD C WHERE C.Parent_id = (:id)")
       .AddEntity(typeof(Child))
       .SetInt32("id", parentId)
       .List<Child>();
```

I'd like to see a better way if possible, losing the compile-time checking is kind of a downer.